# How to keep php session alive after closing browser

Tags: php, session

I tried all the approaches but nothing is working

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600);
session_set_cookie_params(3600);
session_start();
```

Comment: You can’t, sessions are only open for the duration of a browser window being open

Comment: @TommyBs you are wrong. You can control the cookie lifetime with `session.cookie_lifetime` setting in php.ini.

Comment: Well then you’re combining sessions and cookies technically aren’t you

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the lifetime of the cookie itself. Even if session persists on server, it won't work if the cookie is gone. Try setting `session.cookie_lifetime` as well:

```php
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 3600);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600);
```

Comment: Please accept this answer or comment on it if it didn't solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

While sessions can't be preserved after closing the browser, cookies are often what websites use to maintain data after a site has closed. In PHP, saving them looks like this:

```
// from https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
```

```
// and you can read it later like this
echo $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
```